# Run async code in synchronous way in Dart

Tags: asynchronous, dart, async-await

Having the following code:

```
Future<String> checkPrinter() async {
  await new Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return Future.value("Ok");
}

String getPrinterStatus() {
  checkPrinter().then((value) {
    return 'The printer answered: $value';
  }).catchError((_) {
    return "Printer does not respond!";
  });
}

void main() {
  print(getPrinterStatus());
}
```

The output is "null" because the function getPrinterStatus() returns without waiting for checkPrinter to complete (correctly i have a warning telling me that getPrinterStatus does not return a string).

What should i do to make getPrinterStatus to wait for checkPrinter()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no such way to make async code to run in a synchronous way in Dart. So you need to make it so async methods returns a `Future` so it is possible to await the answer.

The problem you have in your code is your are using the `then` method but does not take into account that this method returns a `Future` you should return. So e.g.:

```
String getPrinterStatus() {
  checkPrinter().then((value) {
    return 'The printer answered: $value';
  }).catchError((_){
    return "Printer does not respond!";});
}
```

The two return statements in this example are used for the method your are giving as argument for `then()` and are therefore not used to return from `getPrinterStatus()`.

Instead, `then()` returns a `Future<String>` which will complete with the value.

So you need to carry the `async` through your program. Your code could make use of some language features you gets from marking a method `async` so I have tried to rewrite your code so it works as expected and make use of this features:

```
Future<String> checkPrinter() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return "Ok";
}

// Just an example that the method could be written like this.
// Future.delayed takes a computation as argument.
Future<String> checkPrinterShorter() =>
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () => 'Ok');

Future<String> getPrinterStatus() async {
  try {
    return 'The printer answered: ${await checkPrinter()}';
  } catch (_) {
    return "Printer does not respond!";
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print(await getPrinterStatus());
}
```

There are some changes I think you should notice:

- If a method is marked as `async` the returned value will automatically be packed into a `Future<Type>` so you don't need to return `Future.value("Ok")` but can just return `Ok`.
- If a method is marked as `async` you can use `await` instead of using `then()`. Also, you can use normal exception handling so I have rewritten `getPrinterStatus` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Future<String> getPrinterStatus() async {
    await checkPrinter().then((value) {
      return 'The printer answered: $value';
    }).catchError((_){
      return "Printer does not respond!";});
  }
```

Comment: This is not enough since you also need to make sure main are awaiting the getPrinterStatus().

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPrinterStatus()` is not `async`. `main()` function will never wait for it's execution.

Make it `async`. Refactor your `main()` for something like

```
void main() {
  getPrinterStatus().then((value) {
    print(value);
  }).catchError((_){
    return "Printer does not respond!";});
}
```